# Argument 1 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::send() must implement interface

Tags: httpclient, laravel-8, guzzle

hi I am new to laravel and I am trying to consume the api with laravel 8 I have a problem with my POST and I do not understand

```
public function storeEntreprise(Request $request){
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'phone_number'=>'required',
            'address' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required'
        ]);

        $client = new Client();

        $post = $request->all();

        $url = "http://flexy-job.adsyst-solutions.com/api/entreprises-store";
        $create = $client->request('POST', $url, [
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=UTF8',
            ],
            'form-data' => [
               'name'           => $post['name'],
               'email'        => $post['email'],
               'phone_number'          => $post['phone_number'],
               'address'          => $post['address'],
               'logo'        => $post['logo'],
               'password'       => $post['password'],
               'password_confirmation'      => $post['password_confirmation']
           ]
        ]);
        //dd($create->getBody());
        echo $create->getStatusCode();
        //echo $create->getHeader('Content-Type');
        echo $create->getBody();
        $response = $client->send($create);
        return redirect()->back();

    }
```

Can you help me please

Answer (score 0):

You calling (accidentally?) `$response = $client->send($create);` where `$create` is response of API request you made (`$create = $client->request('POST', $url, ...`).

So `PHP` reports you that you can't pass `ResponseInterface` where `RequestInterface` required.

Also, you `echo`'s body of response, and return redirect response at same time. So browser will not show you API response (because of instance back redirect).